# Two distinct aggregate queries combined: possible? (EF Core 5, SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I've got a table like this:

| id (PK) | name | course | date | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | french | 2016-11-20 | 20 |
| 3 | CARL | french | 2015-09-02 | 30 |
| 4 | Anna | french | 2016-11-20 | 25 |
| 5 | JON | french | 2016-09-02 | 56 |
| 6 | Linda | english | 2016-09-02 | 22 |
| 7 | TIM | english | 2016-11-20 | 23 |
| 8 | JON | english | 2016-11-20 | 44 |

and I'm wondering if it's possible to answer the following two questions with a single query:

- What is the average grade when grouping by course, across all enrolled students in all dates per the course? (this seems more straightforward, as roughly, group on several columns and then take the average of the 'grade' column).
- What is the average number of students that enroll in each course by date? Phrased differently, "in 'English,' since two students were enrolled on 11-20, and one student was enrolled on 09-02, the average number of enrolled students per class date is 1.5.

Is it possible to answer both of these questions with a single query? Or, is it such that because I'd be "grouping by" different columns, I can't achieve this in a single query?

I'm using EF Core 5.0, backed by a SQL Server database, so it would be slick if I could achieve this using the LINQ groupby operator, but if not, I don't mind writing straight SQL if it's more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is going to be somewhat more difficult to combine these, and it's pretty much impossible to do in EF/Linq. I would say it's only worth it if querying the table twice is massively inefficient. Otherwise just do them in either EF or as a single T-SQL batch of two queries.

- The first query could easily be answered in T-SQL

```sql
SELECT
  c.Course,
  AVG(c.Grade * 1.0) AvgGrade
FROM Course c
GROUP BY
  c.Course;
```

And in Linq

```cs
from c in Course
group by c.Course into g
select new {
    Course: g.Key,
    AvgGrade: g.Avg(c2 => c2.Grade * 1.0)
}
```

---

- Likewise, the other query

```sql
SELECT
  c.Course,
  AVG(Count * 1.0) AvgCount
FROM (
    SELECT
      c.Course,
      COUNT(*) Count
    FROM Course c
    GROUP BY
      c.Course,
      c.Date
) c
GROUP BY
  c.Course;
```

And in Linq

```cs
from c in Course
group by new {c.Course, c.Date} into g
select new {
    Course: g.Key.Course,
    Count: g.Count()
} into c2
group by c2.Course into g2
select new {
    Course: g2.Key,
    AvgCount: g2.Average(c3 => c3.Count * 1.0)
}
```

---

**To combine this, you can use the following:**

This is made more complicated by the fact that there is already aggregation, and you can't (mathematically) do averages over averages. So you need to use `SUM / COUNT` and nest the grouping.

```sql
SELECT
  c.Course,
  AVG(Count * 1.0) AvgCount,
  SUM(c.TotalGrades) * 1.0 / SUM(Count) AvgGrade
FROM (
    SELECT
      c.Course,
      COUNT(*) Count,
      SUM(c.Grade) TotalGrades
    FROM Course c
    GROUP BY
      c.Course,
      c.Date
) c
GROUP BY
  c.Course;
```

And in Linq

```cs
from c in Course
group by new {c.Course, c.Date} into g
select new {
    Course: g.Key.Course,
    Count: g.Count(),
    TotalGrades: g.Sum(c3 => c3.Grade)
} into c2
group by c2.Course into g2
select new {
    Course: g2.Key,
    AvgCount: g2.Average(c3 => c3.Count * 1.0).
    AvgGrade: g2.Sum(c3 => c3.TotalGrades) * 1.0 / g2.Sum(c3 => c3.Count)
}
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ceeb69c4a3d27c85f6e666f78d5843a)

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, that's very helpful. I'll read up on groupingsets, though I think the best path forward is two separate queries, for simplicity. For the second query, it's close but I don't think exactly what I need: That gives me a group for every course/date combination, but what I need is just a group for every course, populated with a value of the average count across dates. I could easily achieve this by doing some post processing on each set of groups, but is there a way to do this in a single query? So in English, we had two enrollees on one day, and 1 on another, so the result =1.5

Comment: I'm sorry if that part of my question was unclear.

Comment: Oh then it's much simpler. See edits